# PHP for each loop

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement, foreach

This is what I'm trying to achieve. If All is selected from the drop down menu then I select all clients from my database. For each client it will then run the script creating the html page and then the pdf. This is where I have got to but I cant get it to generate a html page and pdf for each client.

```
<?php
$client_id=$_POST["client_id"];
$date_start=$_POST["date_start"];
$date_end=$_POST["date_end"];

if ($client_id == 'ALL') 
{
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);  

  $query = "select client_id from ca_client_account";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $command="php $result.php $result $date_start $date_end > $result.html";
    exec($command, $output, $status);
    echo $command;
    if ($status!=0) {print_r($output); die("wget failed with status $status"); }

    $command="wkhtmltopdf-i386 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm $result.html $result.pdf";
    exec($command, $output, $status);
    if ($status!=0) die("htmltopdf failed");
  }

}
else
{
  $command="php $client.php $client_id $date_start $date_end > $client.html";
  exec($command, $output, $status);
  if ($status!=0) {print_r($output); die("wget failed with status $status"); }

  $command="wkhtmltopdf-i386 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm $client.html $client.pdf";
  exec($command, $output, $status);
  if ($status!=0) die("htmltopdf failed");
}
?>
```

For a single client everything is perfect. When I try and generate all client statements I cant get it to work.

What am i doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: What output do you get. Any errors?

Comment: the $result variable does not output each client_id as intended. It outputs resource id 3.

Comment: curious, why do you `exec` a php file instead of just `include`ing the file and running the functions like any other? Seems like less hassle to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` will not deliver what you expect here. You need to specify the exact field you intend to echo out. In this case `$row['client_id']` would work.

Comment: Thank you, its almost there but I get Undefined offset:1 now. I used $row[1] instead of $row['client_id'] - im sure this isnt the cause tho

Comment: @TheManiac you are right. I did not mean to change them they are a static file myfile.php - I changed them without thinking when copying in here to make the post generic

Comment: Great -- one more thing: if you want to use `$row['client_id']` instead of `$row[1]` (the former being much more descriptive and a better practice in general) replace your call to `mysql_fetch_array` with [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 2):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how database calls work. In your `$command`, you use `$result`, which is a database requery RESULT HANDLE. It is not a value from the query, it not useable by anything OTHER than mysql_*() functions. A standard query sequence looks something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['some_field'];
```

$result contains a statement handle representing your query results. You use this statement handle to FETCH a row of data. Within that `$row` of data you've fetched, will be the individual data fields you specified in your query. It is THOSE bits of data which you would pass on to your external script.